# Online maps of ski-tour trails of Italy (Aosta Valley, Cogne)?

Tags: skiing, maps, europe, italy

For Austria but not Italy there is awesome http://bergfex.com,
for Italian summer hiking but not winter ski-touring, https://opentopomap.org would do the job, but what about ski-touring in Italy?

Any online maps of ski-tour trails of Italy (Aosta Valley, Cogne)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://www.outdooractive.com has a lot of skitour trails in the Alps, and at least a few in the area you mentioned. AFAIK, they share their database with www.alpenvereinaktiv.com, which is actively supported by the german alpine club.

Comment: i was aware of outdooractive, but got impression that it required the subscription. But no, it does work out of the box: https://www.outdooractive.com/en/tours/#area=1038203&bm=osm%3Awinter&cat=Ski%20Touring&wt=Cogne%20and%20Gran%20Paradiso%20(Geographic%20region)%0A1038203&zc=10,7.08295,45.63446  Thank you!